# Forcing WWW, but want to preserve subdomains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm currently forcing any visitors to use www.mydomain.com in my URL.  However, I'm setting up a mobile site and want to use the subdomain m.mydomain.com.  However, any subdomain that is used redirects to www.mydomain.com.  My current .htaccess for the redirect is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Can I allow the m.mydomain.com redirect with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Would changing your RewriteCond line to as below work for you ? That changes it from just checking to see if the domain begins with `www` to either `www` or `m` , so it seems like what you're looking for.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|m).mydomain.com$
```

Answer (score 0):

Following rules should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|m)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Important to use NC for ignore case comparison, L for marking it last rule. And also dot `.` needs to escaped in RewriteCond.